# How can I update 2 textboxes from JQuery Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, return-value

After success of autocomplete list user selection, I make an Ajax call to fill out some values. I've lost the plot now I want to utilize the returned json values.

Can someone explain to me how I should process the return value and update textboxes. Thanks.

```
$("#txtProductName").autocomplete({
    source: "_ajprodlist.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#txtProductId').val(ui.item.id);
            var custid = $('#txtClientId').val();
            var postData = "prodid="+(ui.item.id)+"&custid="+custid;
            $.ajax({ type: "GET",
                    url: "_ajcustprice.php",
                    data: postData,
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success : function(data) {
                    // alert(data); returns values Ok
                    // [{"custid":"12","custprice":"500","lastqty":"20"}]
                    $("#txtClientPrice").val(data.custprice);    // **** not right
                    $("#txtLastQty").val(data.lastqty);          // **** is it !!!
                    },
                    complete : function() { alert('Complete: Do something.'); },
                    error : function() {alert('Error: Do something.'); }
              });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned data is an array with on element so you need to do:

```
$("#txtClientPrice").val(data[0].custprice); 
$("#txtLastQty").val(data[0].lastqty);
```

assuming of course that you have already corrected the datatype as @gdoron suggests

Comment: Perfect, worked immediately. I'll read up more on the object. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to utilize the returned json values.

Then why are you expecting a `text`? (`dataType: 'text'` instead of `json`)

**Fixed Code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "_ajcustprice.php",
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'json',  // <======= instead of 'text' 
    success: function(data) {
        $("#txtClientPrice").val(data.custprice);
        $("#txtLastQty").val(data.lastqty);
    },
    complete: function() {
        alert('Complete: Do something.');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error: Do something.');
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for fast response gdoron. Sorry, I put the dataType:text in to see if that helped, but it didn't, and then forgot to remove it. If I remove dataType, the default seems to be json anyway. The alert displays the data as a string Ok, but if I try alert(data.custprice) I get undefined. Either way, the textboxes never get updated from the data. Any ideas?

Comment: @KenAshton. Yes, try with `dataType: 'json'` As I answered. Did you try it ?!